# Why am I given a printed boarding pass though I have a mobile pass?

Tags: tickets, turkish-airlines

When I go to counter to check in my luggage, I'm given a printed boarding pass though I have a mobile pass. This happened several times and the last flight was from Istanbul to London.

Why do they give me a printed boarding pass, do they have to? While dropping my luggage, should I mention that I already have a mobile boarding pass?

Comment: Not a duplicate but in the answers is a good reason that might also apply for your airline: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61323/e-boarding-pass-do-you-really-need-the-paper-boarding-pass-for-spirit-airlines

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure whether that answer covers my case, because I receive a printed pass only if I have checked-in luggage (or I visit the counter).

Comment: That is why I did not close as a duplicate.

Comment: Did they attach tags for your checked bags to the printed pass?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes.

Comment: Minor - the printed pass can't go flat like your mobile's battery might, which would disrupt processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there are multiple possible reason.

- In some countries, immigration stamps the boarding pass to allow to later verify that you went through them.
- in some countries, security stamps the pass to allow later to verify that you went through them.
- you will get little sticky chits for your checked luggage, and they usually get stuck onto the boarding pass (but I have seen them stuck on my passport, which I hate)
- some companies require you to hand in the paper boarding pass as proof you really flew when filing your expense report
- their check-in process automatically generates the paper boarding pass, and they hand it to you.

Especially the last one is very common; I usually have an electronic boarding pass, and tell them I don't need a paper pass right in the beginning, and I see them print and discard it anyway.

You can simply toss it if you don't care to have it; but I recommend to keep it until you are on board, just to be sure.

Comment: The 3rd and 5th reasons appear to fit my case.